# Getting directory list from URL in Android

Tags: android, url, directory

How can we get the list of directories from a URL. e.g. from abc.com/myfolders? in Android.

If there are following folders in a URL
**- abc.com/myfolders/folder1

- abc.com/myfolders/folder2

- abc.com/myfolders/folder3

- abc.com/myfolders/folder4**

then how can the list be populated with

**folder1

folder2

folder3

folder4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
String absolutePath = "abc.com/myfolders/folder1";
        String directoryName = null;
        if((absolutePath != null) && (absolutePath.length()>0)){
        int indexOfFileSeparator = absolutePath.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (indexOfFileSeparator >= 0) {
            directoryName = absolutePath.substring(indexOfFileSeparator + 1);
        }
        }
        System.out.println("...shortStr..." + directoryName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a list of folders from a URL, unless the URL is configured to respond with the extra path elements that are valid. URLs are not necessarily a reflection of a server's file system, and therefore folder structure.

It sounds like you want something similar to the standard way some web servers allow for file browsing. I.e., when you navigate to

**http://server/a/path/**

the web server responds with a HTML page that lists the contents of that folder on the server.

Without that, you cannot find out the 'folders' within a URL.

If I've missed the point, then any of the other answers describing String concatenation should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String shortStr = longStr.substring(longStr.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been too late but i am posting this answer for other user's who is looking for same.

You can write PHP web service to get a list of file's located in particular folder of server.

```
<?php
    $path = realpath('uploadAudio');
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
        {
            if (strpos($filename,'extension of file like (.mp3) or (.txt)') !== false)
            $filenm= basename($filename);
?>
             <a href = "yourserverlink/Foldername/foldername/<?php echo $filenm ?>"><?php echo $filenm ?></a><br/>
<?php
       }
?>
```

and then call this service in your java or android code.