# Download picture from web site

Tags: android, web, download

There is a web site somewhere int the Net. It has a picture in first page (in some folder). 
What do I need to download this picture from that place to the Android device? What do a need to ask the site owner to do? May be to put this picture to the certain folder.. etc. Do I need a password/login?
Please help. I didn't do it before.
May be I need a link to read about it more.. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look here:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

I think if the picture is visible from browser you can access it!

Then interesting part is

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoursite.com/&quot; + imageURL); //you can write here any link
File file = new File(fileName);
```

and than:

```
/* Open a connection to that URL. */

    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

    ...

    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
    int current = 0;
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
       baf.append((byte) current);
    }
```

Now you've got a byte[] of the original image and you can write to file system:

```
/* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

`file` is the File object that you can set freely, for example

```
String fileName = "/data/data/image_downloader/image001.png"

  File file = new File(fileName);
```

Look at the link! it contains a full example.

**EDIT**

For a directory listing look at:

[Retrieve ALL images from URL (internet) and save them locally (sdcard) - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050960/retrieve-all-images-from-url-internet-and-save-them-locally-sdcard-android)

and don't forget to look at the useful WebView (use an instance of it to do a lot of things):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: thank you! And another Q. What if the picture is defferent everyday, and has unique name, but the folder is always the same? I need very new pic everytime.

Comment: @Foenix you can't access what you don't have URL to , first rule of the HTTP, so you need to get it somehow

Comment: if I understand right I need all name -  location and picture name exactly

Comment: Are you asking if is it possible to browse de folder to have the name of the file?

Comment: exactly I need to check if the new image appears and download the newest one.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678285/getting-directory-list-from-url-in-android

Comment: but I think you need directory listing activation before you can have the list of all files contained (as you can do with your browser, some time you get "Directory listing not allowed, right?)

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050960/retrieve-all-images-from-url-internet-and-save-them-locally-sdcard-android

Comment: ok, thank you. I will try to download exact image first and then will see the other, I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Yes, but I have the link to the site owner, may be he can do something to help me. But his help will not much - he download that image to site trought the admin-panel, thats all)

Comment: I think the site builder can name the file with a counter or with the date like yyyMMdd.png so you can download the right image every day